# How do you understand loops?

Tags: input, while-loop, do-while

```
    Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=kb.nextInt();
    do{
        System.out.println("How many numbers do you wish to store?");

    }while (n<1);
```

So my question is, I can't figure out how to exit a loop like this and was wondering how one might do so. I'm trying to get the user to have to input a number for an array size until they put in something greater than 0. Obviously this is just a small part of the code, but really I wanted to know the WHY of the answer to this. Loops are something I've never been very good at, and clearly it's important. All I see are the generic syntax answers, but what are we saying if we had to say this in English? Thanks, and all the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've described, the loop will exit when the user enters a value greater than zero. Currently, the part of the code which waits for user input is outside the loop, so you need to move it in, like so:

```
int n = 0; // initialize our loop control variable
do{
    System.out.println("How many numbers do you wish to store?");
    n=kb.nextInt();
}while (n<1);
```

To answer your question about "why", I'm not sure if I completely understand what sort of explanation you're looking for, but basically, this piece of code is saying something like this in plain english:

> Ask the user how many numbers they want to store.
>
> If the user entered a number that is less than zero, ask them again, and continue asking them the same question until they give an number greater than zero

That's about it. Please let me know if I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: That is so incredibly amazing, I've always been shy about posting to forums for help, but you guys have done for me in a few minutes what I've been trying half a semester to find. That being a straight-forward answer. The hardest part starting out, at least from my experience, is figuring out what you are telling the program to do. Therefore having it translated like that is amazing. Thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry sorry, but for some reason, eclipse is giving me an error that says n cannot be resolved to a variable when I put it in as above. When I try to initialize it outside the loop it highlights my scanner and says there is a duplicate local variable.

Comment: @NicholasBrandon oops yeah I forgot about that. The `int n` part is declared inside the block (which is denoted by the curly braces) and exists only within that scope, which the `while` condition cannot see. Basically, The `int n` should be declared before the loop. Inside the loop, remove the `int` part so you just have `n = kb.nextInt()`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: You are legitimately the best.

Comment: @NicholasBrandon No problem, good luck. Also, don't forget to accept an answer (clicking the green check mark on the left side of the question), whichever one helped you most.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying in English, exactly what it's saying right now: 
Do, the stuff inside the loop (that is, the stuff between the '{' and the '}'), while n is less than 1. The logic after "while" says when to stop. Right now, the stuff inside your loop doesn't actually ever change n, so you'll either run it once and quit (if kb.nextInt() is less than 1), or run forever (if it isn't). You have to modify n inside your loop.

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes so much sense.